# Getting Go's HTTP post to emulate curl -d

Tags: go

I am attempting to post content to an nginx server through Go. I have verified that I am able to correctly POST this content through curl, specifically using this command:

```
$ curl http://example.com/myendpoint -d "Some Text"
```

I am able to see this POST, and process it correctly. However, when I try to perform a POST with Go, it is rejected by the server. In the nginx access logs, I see these two lines:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:05:57:34 +0000] "POST /myendpoint HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Go 1.1 package http"
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:05:57:39 +0000] "Some Text" 400 172 "-" "-"
```

The code that I have tried is below:

```
r, err := http.Post(uri, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bytes.NewReader(data))
if err != nil {
  log.Printf("HTTP NOTIFICATION ERROR: %s\n", err)
  return
}
r.Body.Close()
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I presume this is just part of the overall code, so what if you `defer r.Body.Close()`?

Comment: @bishop: Unfortunately, that did not help the problem. The code that I pasted above is in it's own function, that has actually been spun off into a separate goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any particular issue with the code snippets you provided, but you may not be encoding the data as required by [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`'s specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

Try using [`PostForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) instead, which will perform this on your behalf:

```
import (
    "net/url"
)

// ...

r, err := http.PostForm(uri, url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is more convenient for you to convert your post data to []byte, vs url.Values, you can use http.Client.  The code below shows how you can use the Client to process a new http request.

```
var client http.Client
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", myURL, data) // data is of type []byte

if err != nil {     
    // todo: do something
}
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
               // todo: do something
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

    // process your response.
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. Please enlighten me so that I don't make the same mistake.

Comment: probably a misunderstanding of your first paragraph (I also don't understand what you're saying), and your code is functionally exactly the same as the OPs original code (look at the source for Client.Post).

Comment: @JimB - I rushed that answer.  Thanks for clarifying the downvote.